# elements of list in row

Tags: python, csv, pandas

i have few polygons and distance of some points from those polygons. i tried to write in a csv by pandas where distance between each point and polygon will come in separate rows. i got this:

```
poly total inside outside dist
1000   2     0      2     [16015,5678]
1100   1     0      1     [5267]
```

I wanted to get like:

```
poly total inside outside dist
1000   2    0       2     16015
1000   2    0       2     5678
1100   1    0       1     5267
```

I tried the following after looking at this previous q [[How to write nth value of list into csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691707/how-to-write-nth-value-of-list-into-csv-file])

```
distance =[]
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(outSide, ["SHAPE@XY"]):
            px, py = row[0]
            zipPoint=point(px,py)
            Distance.append(int(zipPoint.calDist(PolyCenter)))
for i in distance:
    df.loc[polygon,"distance"]=distance
    df.loc[zipCode,"Total"]=count
    df.loc[zipCode,"Inside"]=insideNum
    df.loc[zipCode,"Outside"]=outsideNum
```

But its giving me the same result in csv. any help is appreciated.

Comment: i just another thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-when-cell-contents-are-lists-create-a-row-for-each-element-in-the-list ). will let you know after trying this.

Answer (score 1):

**Creating dataframe:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df= pd.DataFrame({
        'poly':[1000,1100],
        'total':[2,1],
        'inside':[0,0],
        'outside':[2,1],
        'dist':[[16015,5678],[5267]]
        })

df = df[['poly','total','inside','outside','dist']]

df
Out[]: 
   poly  total  inside  outside           dist
0  1000      2       0        2  [16015, 5678]
1  1100      1       0        1         [5267]
```

**Processing**

```
 new_df = pd.DataFrame({
         col:np.repeat(df[col].values, df['dist'].str.len())
         for col in df.columns.difference(['dist'])
     }).assign(**{'dist':np.concatenate(df['dist'].values)})[df.columns.tolist()]


new_df
Out[]: 
   poly  total  inside  outside   dist
0  1000      2       0        2  16015
1  1000      2       0        2   5678
2  1100      1       0        1   5267
```

Comment: Thanks. got error msg ##TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'##

Comment: i also tried as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-when-cell-contents-are-lists-create-a-row-for-each-element-in-the-list . but getting the same table as my input table.                                                                                                                                                             zip       Total  /  Inside / Outside   /    distance
0  77379   /   2   /    0   /     2   /              [16015, 5678].............
1  77380   /   1    /   0     /   1      /           [5267]

Comment: df=df.astype(np.intp) try running this before processing section.

Comment: i got error :  ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '[16015, 5678]'

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) for get length of `lists` which are repeated by [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with [flattening lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/2901002) and then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) original columns:

```
from  itertools import chain

s = pd.Series(list(chain.from_iterable(df.dist)),
                   index=np.repeat(df.index.values, df.pop('dist').str.len())).rename('dist')
print (s)
0    16015
0     5678
1     5267
Name: dist, dtype: int64

print (df.join(s).reset_index(drop=True))
   poly  total  inside  outside   dist
0  1000      2       0        2  16015
1  1000      2       0        2   5678
2  1100      1       0        1   5267
```

Another solution with [`MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.html):

```
names = ['poly','total', 'inside','outside']
df = df.set_index(names)
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(np.repeat(df.index.values, df.dist.str.len()), names=names)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'dist':list(chain.from_iterable(df.dist))}, index=mux).reset_index()
print (df2)
   poly  total  inside  outside   dist
0  1000      2       0        2  16015
1  1000      2       0        2   5678
2  1100      1       0        1   5267
```

Comment: Thanks. looks like mine is on 32 bit platform. got error msg ##TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'## how can i store 64 to 32?

Comment: It seems it is some numpy error, unfortunately I dont know how simulate this error and how solve it... :(

Answer (score 0):

i got a solution..

`df2=df.fillna(0)
s=df2.apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x['Distances']),axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
s.name="Distance"
df3=df2.drop("Distances",axis=1).join(s)`

it looked like:
    enter code here

```
32811   253  221  32  20
32811  253  221  32  3015
32811   253  221  32  2010
```

Thanks you for your help..still i would appreciate if you can give me a solution for error: 'ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '[16015, 5678]''.